# How to store CSV with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I'm going to write currency converter with JavaScript. Currency will be updated daily in CSV files. I want to figure out how to get values from CSV and the best (efficient) way to store them in application. Thank you!

Comment: Can you use a server side language?

Comment: no, i cant. but still curious how to do this with using it.

Comment: you should be able to fetch the CSV file through Ajax, and then split it yourself. It would however be more convenient to do the parsing in a server side language, and have that language send JSON data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="conversion_table.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="converter.js"></script>
```

The conversion table is just a JavaScript file defining a single object:

```
var conversion_table = 
{
    "USD-GBP": 1.2,
      :
      :
};
```

It is more efficient to use JavaScript objects instead of having to parse a CSV file whenever your user loads your page.

Comment: IMHO, It is always better to perform such operations at server end, ie, converting csv to js object literals.

Comment: True.  Since that file is in JS format, the only rational place for it to be created is on the server.

Answer (score 1):

**Use the [jQuery-CSV](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/) plugin**

With jquery-csv, transforming CSV to JavaScript data structure becomes very simple.

**Using the data:**

> val1,"value 2",val3,val4
>
> "val,1",val2,val3,

**Do:**

```
var array = $.csv.toArray(csv);
```

**Outputs:**

```
[
  ["val1","value 2","val3","val4"],
  ["val,1","val2","val3",""]
]
```

If you want the entries mapped to key:value pairs, just call the *toObjects()* function instead.

**Using the data:**

> foo,bar,baz,fuzz
>
> val1,"value 2",val3,val4
>
> "val,1",val2,val3,

**Do:**

```
var dict = $.csv.toObjects(csv);
```

**Outputs:**

```
[
  {foo:"val1",bar:"value 2",baz:"val3",fuzz:"val4"},
  {foo:"val,1",bar:"val2",baz:"val3",fuzz:""}
]
```

If you need to allow cross-domain requests, this library will also work in Node.js. After the data is converted, assign it to a variable and send a response with the data encoded as 'text/javascript' (Ie JSONP).

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of jquery-csv.*

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a JQuery plugin to convert your CSV data into an array.

This one seems like it ought to do the trick: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/csv